How to print a value stored in a variable in C
How to print a value stored in a variable in C.
I am new in C and I have a little bit of experience in python.
In python if we take num = 30 and if we do print(num). the output is 30.
I want to do the same thing in c but if i write int num = 30; and printf(num) I get a error "Segmentation fault (core dumped)".
I want to Know how to print the value stored in num variable.
#include <stdio.h>

int main() 
{
    int a = 30;
    printf(a); // it gives "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" error
    return 0;
}


printf() needs a format string. In your case it is for example printf("%d",a);. Read the manual pages of printf.

In almost all beginners materials (books, tutorials, classes) I have seen, the second program after "hello world" will show it. What material or courses are you using? What does it say about printing variables? And if you don't have any then you really need to find something, because a programming language (like any spoken or written language) can't be learned by guessing.

Do not assume that the new language you're learning does what the other language you've used did. Read the documentation, or search the internet for an example you can use. Just because Python does something one way does not mean that every other language does as well - in fact, you'll most likely find out that the reverse is true. Few languages work like Python.

Generally, before asking a question about a function, you should study the documentation of the function. However, this reference documentation will likely be overwhelming for a beginner. Therefore, you should be doing a course/tutorial. If you want to learn from English videos, then I would recommend the free CS50 course. If you prefer learning from a book, then you may find this list useful.

What compiler do you use? It should show some warning about providing wrong type of argument in that function call. You should never just ignore warnings without understanding them.

printf does not work line println in arduino. You need to pass C string containing format. For integer it is "%d"
printf("%d\n", a);

Another formats:
printf Format Specifiers



Format Specifier
Data Type
Description




%d or %i
int
Signed decimal integer


%u
unsigned int
Unsigned decimal integer


%f
float/double
Floating-point number (decimal notation)


%e or %E
float/double
Floating-point number (scientific notation)


%g or %G
float/double
Use %f or %e depending on the value


%x or %X
unsigned int
Unsigned hexadecimal integer (lowercase %x or uppercase %X)


%o
unsigned int
Unsigned octal integer


%c
char
Character


%s
char*
String (null-terminated)


%p
void*
Pointer (address in hexadecimal)


%ld
long int
Signed long integer


%lu
unsigned long int
Unsigned long integer


%lld
long long int
Signed long long integer


%llu
unsigned long long int
Unsigned long long integer


%zd
size_t
Unsigned decimal integer for size_t type


%zu
size_t
Unsigned decimal integer (for size_t)


%Lf
long double
Long double floating-point number


%n
int*
Number of characters written so far


%%
-
Literal % character



Additional Flags and Modifiers

Width: You can specify a minimum field width (e.g., %5d).
Precision: For floating-point numbers, you can specify precision (e.g., %.2f for two decimal places).
Zero-padding: Use %0 followed by the width to pad with zeros (e.g., %05d).
Left-justify: Use %- to left-align the output (e.g., %-5d).

printf Flags in C



Flag
Description
Example
Output




-
Left-align the result within the given width
printf("%-5d", 42);
42     (padded with spaces)


+
Always show the sign for signed numbers
printf("%+d", 42);
+42


 
Leave a space before positive numbers (if no sign is shown)
printf("% d", 42);
 42


0
Pad with zeros instead of spaces
printf("%05d", 42);
00042


#
Use an alternate form for octal/hexadecimal numbers
printf("%#x", 255);
0xff


.
Specify precision (used with floats, integers, and strings)
printf("%.2f", 3.14159);
3.14


*
Width or precision is specified by an argument
printf("%*d", 5, 42);
   42 (width specified)



Special characters in printf



Character
Name
Description
Example
Output




\n
Newline
Moves the cursor to the next line.
printf("Hello\nWorld");
Hello  World


\t
Horizontal Tab
Inserts a tab character, often equal to 4 or 8 spaces.
printf("Hello\tWorld");
Hello   World


\\
Backslash
Inserts a literal backslash (\).
printf("Path: C:\\");
Path: C:\


\"
Double Quote
Inserts a literal double-quote character (").
printf("\"Hello\"");
"Hello"


\'
Single Quote
Inserts a literal single-quote character (').
printf("\'A\'");
'A'


\r
Carriage Return
Moves the cursor to the beginning of the current line (often used in combination with \n).
printf("Hello\rWorld");
World (replaces Hello)


\b
Backspace
Moves the cursor back one space (does not delete characters).
printf("123\b4");
124 (deletes 3)


\f
Formfeed
Moves the cursor to the next page (rarely used).
N/A
N/A


\v
Vertical Tab
Moves the cursor to the next vertical tab position (rarely used).
N/A
N/A


\a
Bell
Produces an audible or visual alert, often a beep.
printf("\a");
A system beep or flash on supported systems



\a (Bell) Its use is limited to terminals or systems that support it.
printf Format Specifiers in C
The printf function in C/C++ is used to output formatted strings. Each format specifier begins with a % and is followed by a character that defines the type of data being printed. Here's a detailed list of the most common format specifiers, along with examples.
Integer Formats
%d or %i

Description: Prints an integer as a signed decimal number.
Example:
int x = -42;
printf("%d\n", x);  // Output: -42
printf("%i\n", x);  // Output: -42



%u

Description: Prints an unsigned integer.
Example:
unsigned int x = 42;
printf("%u\n", x);  // Output: 42



%x or %X

Description: Prints an unsigned integer in hexadecimal format (lowercase or uppercase).
Example:
unsigned int x = 255;
printf("%x\n", x);  // Output: ff
printf("%X\n", x);  // Output: FF



%o

Description: Prints an unsigned integer in octal format.
Example:
unsigned int x = 255;
printf("%o\n", x);  // Output: 377



Floating-Point Formats
%f

Description: Prints a floating-point number in fixed-point notation.
Example:
float x = 3.14159;
printf("%f\n", x);  // Output: 3.141590



%e or %E

Description: Prints a floating-point number in scientific notation (lowercase or uppercase).
Example:
double x = 1234567.89;
printf("%e\n", x);  // Output: 1.234568e+06
printf("%E\n", x);  // Output: 1.234568E+06



%g or %G

Description: Prints a floating-point number in either fixed-point or scientific notation, depending on its value.
Example:
double x = 1234567.89;
printf("%g\n", x);  // Output: 1.23457e+06
printf("%G\n", x);  // Output: 1.23457E+06



Character and String Formats
%c

Description: Prints a single character.
Example:
char ch = 'A';
printf("%c\n", ch);  // Output: A



%s

Description: Prints a string (null-terminated character array).
Example:
char str[] = "Hello, World!";
printf("%s\n", str);  // Output: Hello, World!



Pointer Format
%p

Description: Prints a pointer (memory address).
Example:
int x = 42;
printf("%p\n", (void*)&x);  // Output: 0x7ffee2b8e798 (example)



Length Modifiers
%ld or %li

Description: Prints a long signed decimal integer.
Example:
long int x = 123456789L;
printf("%ld\n", x);  // Output: 123456789



%lu

Description: Prints an unsigned long integer.
Example:
unsigned long int x = 123456789UL;
printf("%lu\n", x);  // Output: 123456789



%lld or %lli

Description: Prints a long long signed decimal integer.
Example:
long long int x = 123456789012345LL;
printf("%lld\n", x);  // Output: 123456789012345



%llu

Description: Prints an unsigned long long integer.
Example:
unsigned long long int x = 123456789012345ULL;
printf("%llu\n", x);  // Output: 123456789012345



Width and Precision

Width: Specifies the minimum number of characters to be printed.
Precision: Specifies the number of digits after the decimal point (for floating-point values) or the maximum number of characters in a string.

Example with width:
int x = 42;
printf("%5d\n", x);  // Output: '   42' (padded with spaces)

